# Impossible to update catalina OS

Tags: macos

I tried to update my mojave to catalina in order to update Xcode... But impossible I have 27Gb Free space but all time this error:

```
an error occurred while installing the selected updates
```

And after each error I have 8Gb in less, so if I continue I while arrive to not have free space, I don't know how to delete this fail load on my system storage.

I found that 8Gb are add in private/var/folders (never touch this folders) just reboot in safe mode, this will erase temporary file...

Comment: This is off-topic here, but what unit is "go"?

Comment: it's Giga octet

Comment: What is an octet?

Comment: My HDD is 120 Go, I have 90Go from the system T_T

Comment: It's 8 bit of data

Comment: Ah ok. In English that's "gigabytes" (GB).

Comment: sry i'm french ^^

Comment: You should ask this on Ask Different. A mac specific site.

Comment: please refer to this article https://touseef-ahmad.medium.com/unable-to-install-catalina-3b9bbe185af9

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://blog.macsales.com/53855-how-to-fix-macos-catalina-installation-issues/):

> A clean install uses up around 20 GB of storage space. In addition,
> you need to allow for space for your user data, applications, and
> future updates. As if that weren’t enough, you should keep at least 10
> to15 percent of the startup drive free to ensure adequate performance.
> I normally suggest a good deal more free space than that, but here
> we’re just talking about a minimum to ensure you can install and use
> macOS Catalina.

So the solution may be freeing up to 30 GB of space, just to be sure.

You can try [this](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) utility to better identify some files to delete.

Comment: Thank you, my higher problem is this accumulation of data after each try of upgrade, I successed to test with little more 30Go but same issue. Now because of this test I have less free space T_T I will arrive to have 100% data only for system, it's crazy

Comment: Normally MacOs leaves a copy of the OS installer in the application folder; check for multiple copies of it. I recommend to use Grand Perspective; it's really helpful in identifying large files and delete them

Comment: Please don’t post answers to off-topic questions.